# Is there any way to get iTerm2 to color each new tab with a different color (using Oh My Zsh on Mac)?

Tags: terminal, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I like having different colored tabs in iTerm2 to quickly know what each tab refers to.  I can, of course, set them manually each time I open them, or download a script that will allow me to do that from the terminal itself (see pic for an example -- I've manually changed each tab's color). I was wondering whether there was a way (built in to iTerm2 or through an Oh My Zsh script) to simply have iTerm2 use a new (possibly random) color for the tab automatically on opening the tab?  I have googled and can't find anything except a way to have SSH have a different tab color.  Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

to support random color automaticly when using `color` without argument

add the following lines to `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
PRELINE="\r\033[A"

function random {
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
}

function color {
    case $1 in
    green)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;57\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;197\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;77\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    red)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;270\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;60\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;83\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    orange)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;227\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;143\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;10\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    *)
    random
    esac
}

#color    #uncomment to enable automatically set random color when tab created
```

After each time a new iterm2 tab created, use command `color` to automaticly give it a new/random color.

if you want the iterm2-tab color set automatically whenever it is created, then .just add `color` to then end of `.zshrc` / `.profile` or just after the `function color`

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .bashrc/.zshrc/.whateverrc file to get a random tab color every time you open a new tab in iTerm2:

```
function tabcolor {
  echo -n -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$1\a"
  echo -n -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$2\a"
  echo -n -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$3\a"
}

tabcolor $(jot -r 1 0 255) $(jot -r 1 0 255) $(jot -r 1 0 255)
```